# Choosing the order of 2 appended recipes in Yocto

Tags: yocto

An appended recipe is conflicting with another in terms of priority:

- meta layer: *linux-firmware_git.bb*
- meta-raspberrypi: *linux-firmware_git.bbappend*
- meta-mylayer: *linux-firmware_git.bbappend*

I want the appended recipe from *meta-mylayer* to be applied **after** the one from *meta-raspberrypi* otherwise I have errors during the `do_install` task. How to force this ?

Answer (score 1):

bbappend files are applied in order of increasing layer priority, so you need to make sure meta-mylayer has a higher BBFILE_PRIORITY assigned in its conf/layer.conf than the RPi layer's.

See also http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-BBFILE_PRIORITY